# SilverStripe custom form retrieve values for form fields

Tags: forms, frontend, silverstripe

I have a problem with my front end admin update page. How can I retrieve values from a SiteTree page and populate it into a custom form? Is the setValue($values) function the only way? If yes, which is the best method to get the page variable?

I am using this:

```php
$evens = Versioned::get_by_stage('PageCalendrierEvenement', 'Stage')->byID($evenID);
```

I'm getting values from an ID of a draft page. After I get variables and values like that:

```php
$field = new TextField('Titre', 'Titre'); 
$field->setValue($evens->Titre);
```

or

```php
new TextField('Titre','Titre', $evens->Titre);
```

Which is the better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is 2 part:

1. Use `TextField::create($constructor, $args)` instead of `new` (optional, but not doing so is a pet hate of mine).
2. Set all fields at once: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Form.html#_loadDataFrom

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please be aware that links might break in the future. Please consider giving at least a summary of the relevant information you linked to.

Comment: Do you have an exemple how to use loadDataForm? Thanks!

Comment: Work! Thats awesome! Thanks you!